# C++ cin problems. not capturing input from user

Tags: c++, stdin, std, cin

I have the following method which is not capturing anything from the user.If I input New Band for the artist name, it only captures "New" and it lefts out "Band". If I use cin.getline() instead nothing is captured. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
char* artist = new char [256];

char * getArtist()
{
    cout << "Enter Artist of CD: " << endl;
    cin >> artist;      
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cout << "artist is " << artist << endl;
    return artist;
}
```

This worked just fine. Thank you Roger

```
std::string getArtist()

{   

    cout << "Enter Artist of CD: " << endl;

    while(true){            

        if ( getline(cin, artist)){

        }

    cout << "artist is " << artist << '\n';

    }

    return artist;

}
```

Comment: Please use `std::string` and don't ever use `new[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string getArtist() {
  using namespace std;
  while (true) {
    cout << "Enter Artist of CD: " << endl;
    string artist;
    if (getline(cin, artist)) {             // <-- pay attention to this line
      if (artist.empty()) { // if desired
        cout << "try again\n";
        continue;
      }
      cout << "artist is " << artist << '\n';
      return artist;
    }
    else if (cin.eof()) { // failed due to eof
      // notice this is checked only *after* the
      // stream is (in the above if condition)

      // handle error, probably throw exception
      throw runtime_error("unexpected input error");
    }
  }
}
```

The whole thing is a general improvement, but the use of *getline* is possibly the most significant for your question.

```
void example_use() {
  std::string artist = getArtist();
  //...

  // it's really that simple: no allocations to worry about, etc.
}
```

Comment: This works fine except that everytime I get "try again". Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @user: As written above, that will only happen if the input is empty (the user pressed enter at the prompt without typing anything).  Perhaps you miscopied it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the specified behaviour; `istream`s only read up to a space or a newline. If you want an entire line, you use the `getline` method, as you already discovered.

Also, please use `std::string` instead of `char*` in any new C++ code, unless there are very good reasons otherwise. In this case, it will save you from all kinds of problems like buffer overflows, without any extra effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have white space separators in your input, you need to use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) for your input. That would make your ignore unnecessary.